# Conditional expected value of $Y=X^2$ given $X$

Tags: probability

Given $X$ is a uniform random variable, how can I compute $E(Y\mid X)$ if $Y=X^2$? Can I assume that $(X,Y)$ is also a uniform random variable?

Comment: What would you expect $X^2$ to be for any given $X$?

Comment: But you [already asked this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2403905/), no?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your case $E(Y\mid X) = X^2$, or (depending on your notational preference) $E(Y\mid X=x) = x^2$.  Your supposition that $(X,Y)$ is uniform is false. If that were the case, the probability mass would be spread out uniformly over the unit square.  In fact it is concentrated on part of the graph of $y=x^2$.